# How to display lines with Chinese letters on DevC++?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, unicode, dev-c++, kanji

What I want is to display a line with a Chinese letter, entered by the user. Though the program DevC++.

This is my code:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    using namespace std;
    extern wostream wcout;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::wstring kanji = L"?";
    //std::wchar_t stop = L"0";
    std::wcout << L"\n\nWelcome to the Chinese letter program\n";
    std::wcout << L"The program will ask you for one Chinese letter\n";
    std::wcout << L"Then press enter, and a message will display.\n";
    std::wcout << L"Once you are done,you can enter another Chinese letter\n";
    std::wcout << L"To exit just close the Ubuntu's terminal'\n\n";
        for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++){
            std::wcout << L"Give me one Chinese letter...";
                wcin >> kanji;
                std::wcout << L"The Chinese letter is \"" << kanji << "\".\n\n";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

What matters to me is the "The Chinese letter is "(kanji)"." line. When I do what the program says I get "The Chinese letter is "?".". So the problem is that DevC++ doesn't show the Chinese letters correctly, even when I using the wcin and wcout things.

Note I am using DevC++ on Ubuntu, through wine.

Answer (score 0):

Do your console support Chinese encoding? take a look at this post
[How to print a Chinese character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525779/how-to-print-a-chinese-character)

Comment: The ubuntu's terminal do supports Chinese encoding, I know it because I can write Chinese characters with no problem. On the other side DevC++ don't seem to support that, if I write a Chinese character I only get question marks.

Comment: Dev C++ is pretty old, and produced in an era where C++'s cross platform wide character support was much more difficult than it is today (and to be honest it's still pretty hard to work with). You may have to find something more up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved using html to complement what DevC++ cannot do, which is working with Chinese letters.

The c++ code ended up like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string kanji = "?";
    int x2=0;
    int x3=1;
    std::cout << "\n\nWelcome to the Chinese letter program\n";
    std::cout << "This program will display a line or lines with Chinese letters\n";
    std::cout << "through a jury-rigged method.\n";
    std::cout << "This will generate an html code, that must be\n";
    std::cout << "transformed into an html file.\n";
    std::cout << "To exit just close the Ubuntu's terminal.\n";
    std::cout << "Note: the only catch is that it must be applied\n";
    std::cout << "a backspace where you gave enter into the html code.\n\n";

    std::cout << "\n\nHow many Chinese letters will be?";
    cin >> x2;

    std::cout << "\n\n<html>\n";
    std::cout << "<header><title>Chinese letters</title></header>\n";
    std::cout << "<body>\n";
        for(int x = 0; x < x2; x++){
            std::cout << "<!-- (Loop " << x3 << "/" << x2 << ") -->\n";
            std::cout << "The Chinese letter is \"";
            cin >> kanji;
            std::cout << "\".\n";
            std::cout << "<br><br>\n";
            x3++;
        }
    std::cout << "</body>\n";
    std::cout << "</html>\n";
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Which generates an html code that can display Chinese letters. For example like this:

```
<html>
<header><title>Chinese letters</title></header>
<body>
<!-- (Loop 1/2) -->
The Chinese letter is "銀".
<br><br>
<!-- (Loop 2/2) -->
The Chinese letter is "囗".
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Ending with what was expected from the c++ program:

```
The Chinese letter is "銀".

The Chinese letter is "囗".
```

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done in DevC++ without using jury-rigged tricks. So the problem was solved using that way or using java instead of c++.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class kanji { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);  
         String kanji;
         System.out.println("\nWelcome to the Chinese letter program");
         System.out.println("This program will display one line with a Chinese letter.\n");
         System.out.println("Which is the Chinese letter?");
         kanji = ob.nextLine();
         System.out.println("\nThe Chinese letter is \"" + kanji + "\".\n");

    } //main
} //class
```

Having no problems at all with the Chinese letters.

It can be compiled in the terminal with "javac -g kanji.java", and executed with "java kanji".